# Tree like widget in GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I have a requirement of a tree like widget in a `CellTable` and so far I haven't found anything that works seamlessly. So, I was evaluating celltree.

As most of my functionality is ready with `CellTable` and as tree like requirement has come very late into the development I want to incorporate it somehow in the `CellTable` itself rather than re-writing the whole UI again.

Is it possible to do with `CellTable`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CellTable implement a custom Cell and feed it an implementation of TreeViewModel. Easier said than done, but that's the basic approach I would use.